# LiveCharts (LVC) WPF - get chart from DataClick event

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I've got a 'dashboard' with several charts on it. One of them is a pie chart with a number of series.

LiveCharts has a DataClick event

```
DataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartPoint)
```

`sender` is of type `PieSlice`. How can i access `SeriesCollection` from that event or, alternatively, chart name / id?

What I am trying to achieve is access chart that sent the event, then it's series collection and check which of the series / pie slice fired the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, don't use `events`, use `commands` - that's the MVVM way. i.e.

```
<LiveCharts:PieChart DataClickCommand="{Binding DrillDownCommand}" Series="{Binding MySeries}" ...>
```

Note the binding to `MySeries`:

```
public SeriesCollection MySeries
{
    get
    {
        var seriesCollection = new SeriesCollection(mapper);

        seriesCollection.Add(new PieSeries()
        {
            Title = "My display name",
            Values = new ChartValues<YourObjectHere>(new[] { anInstanceOfYourObjectHere })
        });

        return seriesCollection;
    }
}
```

And about handling the command:

```
public ICommand DrillDownCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<ChartPoint>(this.OnDrillDownCommand);
    }
}

private void OnDrillDownCommand(ChartPoint chartPoint)
{
    // access the chartPoint.Instance (Cast it to YourObjectHere and access its properties)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with arguments, not the sender. The second parameter is `ChartPoint`, that cointains `SeriesView`. So just access it and use it's `Title`:

```
    private void Chart_OnDataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartpoint) {
        MessageBox.Show(chartpoint.SeriesView.Title);
    }
```

> How can i access SeriesCollection from that event or, alternatively, chart name / id?

SeriesView is not the whole SeriesCollection, but `Series` you clicked on. And you can have it's name